# How to get size of paragraphs in office.word with interop

Tags: ms-word, word-interop

I have a single page office word (.docx) file, there are several paragraphs inside. I need to get the total height of all paragraphs.

I tried with Openxml sdk, but failed, because openxml only handle the structure of docx file, not layout.
Is it possible to use word.interop (c#) and how?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried before we can answer your question.  That's how Stackoverflow is supposed to work.  In the meantime, if you can tell us why you need the bounding box someone may be able to suggest an easier approach to solving your problem.

Comment: thanks, freeflow, what I need is the height of those paragraphs. will post code later.

Comment: Its a common problem on Stackoverflow that OPs get fixated on how they want to solve a problem rather than explaining what the problem is.  Your response is a good example of that.  What problem are you trying to solve that requires you to know the height of the paragraphs.

Comment: In short, I need to convert paragraph to image which will be a background of a canvas, and on Canvas there are some free hand writing strokes which will be aligned with the content of those paragraph.

Comment: Open a new document that is invisible to the user.  Select your paragraphs and copy them. Paste the copied text to a new document as an image. You now have an inline image in your hidden document from which you can obtain the information you need.

Comment: Just not get "Paste the copied text to a new document as an image.", but I will tried first on my own. Thank you.